# Android, Java Via HttpClient - HttpPut

Tags: java, android, node.js, curl, couchdb

I'm working on native android app using couchdb server side.
Everytime I've tried to upload attachment to document, It's throws ClientProtocolException

```
public JSONObject uploadPicture(PutAttachment putAttachment) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(baseUrl() + putAttachment.getDbName() + "/" + putAttachment.getDocName() + "/attachment?rev=" + putAttachment.getRev());

        ByteArrayEntity img = new ByteArrayEntity(putAttachment.getByteImg());
        httpPut.setEntity(img);

        httpPut.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + (int) img.getContentLength());
        httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "image/png");
        httpPut.setHeader(authenticate());

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            obj = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return obj;

}
```